# Convert WSQ string to png/jpg

Tags: javascript, fingerprint

I am trying to convert a WSQ fingerprint string to jpg/png using Javascript code. Is this even possible?

I can't use third party programmes to do so hence am trying to view it in my application

Comment: what is a WSQ "fingerprint string"?

Comment: It is a secure string used for fingerprinting, The image of your fingerprint is stored in this format.

Comment: It's not secured, it's just a image format optimized for fingerprint greyscale image